# Several parameters function VBA ( Tried with call and parenthesis and without parenthesis and still not working)

Tags: regex, string, vba

I know this will be some stupid thing I overlooked, but I swear I have no clue what is wrong with this code:

```
Public Sub sustituirExpresion(ByVal Exp As String, ByVal Str As String, ByVal cell As String, ByVal hoja As String)
 Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = Exp
    Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = Str
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set Myrange = Sheets(hoja).Range(cell)

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        sustituirExpresion = (regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace))
    End If

End Sub
Sub limpiarDescripcion()
    Dim resultado As String

    resultado = sustituirExpresion "/s+", " ", "AD2", "Hoja1"
    MsgBox resultado


End Sub
```

I tried to use the Call form too:

```
resultado = Call sustituirExpresion ("/s+", " ", "AD2", "Hoja1")
```

But it still throw me an error "Expected function or varibale" and I can't understand why.

¿Any leads?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You've tried without both `Call` and parentheses, you've tried with both `Call` and parentheses. What's left to try is with one but without another.

Comment: I don't understand. This was also tried: resultado = sustituirExpresion ("/s+", " ", "AD2", "Hoja1")

Comment: sustituirExpresion is a Sub. Change it to a Function.

Comment: subs cant return, use function x(args) as z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things here:

- Replace the signature with `Public Function sustituirExpresion(ByVal Exp As String, ByVal Str As String, ByVal cell As String, ByVal hoja As String) As String` to turn a `Sub` to a `Function`
- You do not need `.MultiLine = True`, keep it `False` because your regex `/\s+` does not contain any `^` or  `$` to re-define the behavior of (they will match start/end of *line* if you set `Multiline` to *True*).
- You do not need the parentheses around the `regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)`, use `sustituirExpresion = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)`